# Eclipse SVN merge and Revision Graph

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, subclipse

I'm trying to get an revision graph like the linked one below
http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3062/2657955813_3a22ec4170_o.png

But i'm not able to make merging visible in the graph. Are there specific things to do while merging to make this lines visible? I'm a complete beginner at SVN.

I'm using Eclipse Juno on linux Mint with the subversion Plugin from tigris.org and tried to merge a branch of my website back into the trunk

Thx, Fritz

Answer (score 0):

See the section on showing merge information here:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/graph.html

Essentially the performance of gathering the SVN logs is not good enough to support it so it is an "on-demand" feature only.